# Can I develop chrome extensions that work with chromes pdf viewer

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pdf-viewer

Is it possible to develop a chrome extension that also works with chrome's PDF-Viewer.

In particular I would like to have the [Google Dictionary Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) working with PDFs, so that I can doubleclick a word in a PDF and get an instant translation.

Answer (score 1):

You can run chrome extension in pdf viewer but in limited way: you can insert a menu item (context menu). This [English dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/english-dictionary-transl/neomigpibafpboiknmijddgnncengfnm) does the same you want to: works by double-click on any page, but in pdf viewer it works only by right-clicking.